# TypeError: Foo is not a function when using a closure

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing closures, and i get this error when running a simple closure

> TypeError: owl is not a function

I think i did everything right.

```
const revers = (str) => {
  return str.split("").reverse().join("");

    const inner = () => {
       console.log(str);
    }

    return inner;
} 

 const owl = revers("owls are cool");

 owl();
```

Comment: `const inner` is dead code.  It is preceeded by a return statement.

Comment: You're returning a string in `revers`. Not a function. Is that supposed to be `str = str.split("").reverse().join("")`

Comment: how can i fix it, so that it can be a closure.

Comment: Figure out what you were trying to do with the first line of code.  Obviously the return is not what you wanted to happen.

Comment: how would i be able to call the console.log within the function by using a closure

Comment: You're ignoring the problem that we are pointing out.  Ignore the closure, that's not your issue.  Fix your return statement on the str.split line

Comment: i fixed it with you're folks help.

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn't have used the return on the `str.split("").reverse().join("");`

so i put it in a variable and logged it into the inner function. I guess this is a practical way to use a closure. Cause i didn't have to call the console.log outside of the function scope.

```
const revers = (str) => {
  let spl = str.split("").reverse().join("");

    const inner = () => {
       console.log(spl);
    }
    return inner;

} 

 const owl = revers("owls are cool");

 owl();
```

**output**

`looc era slwo`